# Concat 2 strings erlang and send with http

Tags: http, erlang

I'm trying to concat 2 variables Address and Payload. After that I want to send them with http to a server but I have 2 problems. When i try to concat the 2 variables with a delimiter ';' it doesn't work. Also sending the data of Payload or Address doesn't work. This is my code:

```
handle_rx(Gateway, #link{devaddr=DevAddr}=Link, #rxdata{port=Port, data= RxData }, RxQ)->
    Data = base64:encode(RxData),
    Devaddr = base64:encode(DevAddr),
    TextAddr="Device address: ",
    TextPayload="Payload: ",
    Address = string:concat(TextAddr, Devaddr),
    Payload = string:concat(TextPayload, Data),
    Json=string:join([Address,Payload], "; "),
    file:write_file("/tmp/foo.txt", io_lib:fwrite("~s.\n", [Json] )),
    inets:start(),
    ssl:start(),
    httpc:request(post, {"http://192.168.0.121/apiv1/lorapacket/rx", [], "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Address },[],[]),
    ok;
handle_rx(_Gateway, _Link, RxData, _RxQ) ->
    {error, {unexpected_data, RxData}}.
```

I have no errors that I can show you. When I write Address or Payload individually to the file it works but sending doesn't work...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're not passing `Json` to the HTTP request at all..?

Comment: I know, I figured that if he doesn't send Address to the server, he won't send Json either.

Comment: Have you tried printing the return value of `httpc:request`? It might be returning some error. Try `Response = httpc:request(...), io:format("~p~n", [Response])`.

Comment: That would help but i can't run this code with Erlang so I don't get a response back. The code runs when I send a packet and i don't run it with erlang...

Comment: I meant modify the `httpc:request` line in the code in the question to store the returned value and print it. `httpc:request` will not throw or print any errors, it'll just return the error value, which you need to print to debug further.

Comment: I did this instead to know the error but it doesn't work: file:write_file("/tmp/error.txt", io_lib:fwrite("~s.\n", [Response] )) is there a syntax error in this line?

Comment: Try `~p` instead of `~s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i try to concat the 2 variables with a delimiter ';' it doesn't work.

```
5> string:join(["hello", <<"world">>], ";").
[104,101,108,108,111,59|<<"world">>]

6> string:join(["hello", "world"], ";").    
"hello;world"
```

`base64:encode()` returns a binary, yet `string:join()` requires string arguments.  You can do this:

```
7> string:join(["hello", binary_to_list(<<"world">>)], ";").
"hello;world"
```

**Response to comment**:

In erlang the string `"abc"` is equivalent to the list `[97,98,99]`.  However, the binary syntax `<<"abc">>` is *not* equivalent to `<<[97,98,99]>>`, rather the binary syntax `<<"abc">>` is special short hand notation for the binary `<<97, 98, 99>>`.

Therefore, if you write:

```
Address = [97,98,99].
```

then the code:

```
Bin = <<Address>>.
```

after variable substitution becomes:

```
Bin = <<[97,98,99]>>.
```

and that isn't legal binary syntax.

If you need to convert a string/list contained in a variable, like Address, to a binary, you use `list_to_binary(Address)`--not `<<Address>>`.

In your code here:

```
Json = string:join([binary_to_list(<<Address>>),
                    binary_to_list(<<Pa‌​yload>>)], 
                    ";").
```

Address and Payload were previously assigned the return value of  `string:concat()`, which returns a string, so there is no reason to (attempt) to convert Address to a binary with `<<Address>>`, then immediately convert the binary back to a string with `binary_to_list()`.  Instead, you would just write:

```
Json = string:join(Address, Payload, ";")
```

The problem with your original code is that you called `string:concat()` with a string as the first argument and a binary as the second argument--yet `string:concat()` takes two string arguments.  You can use `binary_to_list()` to convert a binary to the string that you need for the second argument.

> Sorry I'm new to Erlang

As with any language, you have to study the basics and write numerous toy examples before you can start writing code that actually does something.

Comment: I tried this: Json = string:join([binary_to_list(<<Address>>),binary_to_list(<<Payload>>)], ";"). But it Doesn't work. Sorry I'm new to Erlang :) Thanks for the help

Comment: @MrDloof, See my response to your comment at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to concatenate strings. It is called `iolist` and is one of best things in Erlang:

```
1> RxData = "Hello World!", DevAddr = "Earth",
1> Data = base64:encode(RxData), Devaddr = base64:encode(DevAddr),
1> TextAddr="Device address", TextPayload="Payload",
1> Json=["{'", TextAddr, "': '", Devaddr, "', '", TextPayload, "': '", Data, "'}"].
["{'","Device address","': '",<<"RWFydGg=">>,"', '",
 "Payload","': '",<<"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh">>,"'}"]
2> file:write_file("/tmp/foo.txt", Json).
ok
3> file:read_file("/tmp/foo.txt").
{ok,<<"{'Device address': 'RWFydGg=', 'Payload': 'SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh'}">>}
```